# <video> element receives as source a MediaStream, even although its src property is set to an object URL string

Tags: reactjs, typescript, html5-video, mediastream, web-mediarecorder

I'm trying to record video in a React + TS component. I want to conditionally render the video player: if the user is recording, the video player source should be the live stream (`MediaStream`), but if the recording is finished, the video player source should change from the live stream to the newly created `recordingURL` (created with `URL.createObjectURL(blob)`.

As you can see, I'm replacing the one `<video/>` tag with another, because [I cannot just use `HTMLMediaElement.srcObject` to set a source different from a `MediaStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/srcObject#browser_compatibility).

```js
<div className="VideoRecorder flex flex-col mx-2">
    {recordingURL.current! ? (
         <video
             src={recordingURL.current}
             playsInline
             controls
             className="RECORDED"
         />
     ) : (
         <video
             ref={(ref) => {
                  if (ref)
                      ref.srcObject = recordingStream.current;
             }}
             autoPlay
             className="LIVE"
         />
     )}
</div>
```

When the recording starts, the video player successfully displays the live `MediaStream`. When the recording stops the video player **does change** (I checked the render HTML and the video player with the `className="RECORDED"` comes in replacement for the one with the `className="LIVE"`), the `recordingURL.current` **also changes** from `null` to the object URL `string` **but the problem is that, somehow, this new video player is still showing a live stream**

The code below shows the relevant `state` and `ref` managing for the `MediaRecorder`.

```js
const recordingURL = useRef<null | string>(null);

const stopRecording = () => {
    const blob = new Blob(recordedChunks.current, {
        type: mediaConstraints.audio ? 'audio/mpeg' : 'video/mp4'
    });
    setIsRecording(false);

    recordingURL.current = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    setBlob(blob);
};

const initializeDevice = async () => {
    try {
        recordingStream.current = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
            mediaConstraints
        );

        setPermissionGranted(true);

        mediaRecorder.current = new MediaRecorder(recordingStream.current);
        mediaRecorder.current!.ondataavailable = saveRecordingChunks;
        mediaRecorder.current!.onstop = stopRecording;
    } catch (error: any) {
        // Exception handling...
    }
};
```

And this HTML fragment shows the `<video>` element that replaced the recording one. As you can see, its `src` is set to a url, yet this component actually shows the data stream:

```
<video class="RECORDED" src="blob:http://localhost:3000/af437ac7-e77e-4d5b-a2f5-2645507448ed" playsinline="" controls=""></video>
```

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: I don't know reactjs that much, is the whole element being replaced or only the new attributes added? If the latter you might need the `ref` callback to explicitely set `srcObject` to `null`, even in the `recordingURL.current` case `srcObject` takes precedance over `src`.

Comment: The whole element is being replaced. The solution is to add a `key` parameter for each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `key` parameter to each `<video>` element solved the problem.

Comment: what is "key" parameter?